# capybara, selenium interact with hidden or display: none css properties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I'm using similar construction:

```
<div class="edit" style="visibility: hidden;">
  <a href="some_path" id="edit_item">Edit</a>
</div>
```

Then I hover mouse this element become visible, but I have difficult to interact this actions with tests(using cucumber, capybara, selenium).

I get an error

> Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotDisplayedError)

I tried to use [Element.trigger(event)](http://rdoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Element#trigger-instance_method) with mouseover, but it doesn't work in selenium...
How I can interact with this element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this problem using execute_script from capybara:

```
When /^I hover element "([^""]*)"(?: within "([^""]*)")?$/ do |id,selector|
  with_scope(selector) do
    page.execute_script("$('#{id}').mouseover();")
  end
end

When /^I click in hide element "([^""]*)"(?: within "([^""]*)")?$/ do |id,selector|
  with_scope(selector) do
    page.execute_script("$('#{id}').click();")
  end
end
```

but this solution doesn't work with css - display: none;

Comment: Be aware that `with_scope` has no effect on `execute_script`.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, have in mind that [`execute_script`](https://capybara-test-helpers.netlify.app/api/#execute-script) can be called in elements, which provides [better async guarantees](https://capybara-test-helpers.netlify.app/guide/advanced/synchronization):

```rb
When /^I hover element "([^""]*)"(?: within "([^""]*)")?$/ do |id,selector|
  element = within(selector) { find_by_id(id) }
  element.execute_script('this.mouseover()')
end

When /^I click in hide element "([^""]*)"(?: within "([^""]*)")?$/ do |id,selector|
  within(selector) { find_by_id(id) }.execute_script('this.click()')
end
```

Specifying `visible: :all` is another way to find hidden elements:

```rb
find('.edit', visible: :all).hover
click_link('Edit')
```

That said, interacting with hidden elements may hide real issues in the UI that won't allow a user to perform an interaction, so it's better to use it sparingly.